# checking if file exists: performance of isfile Vs open(path)

Tags: python, file, exists

Which one should I use to maximize performance? `os.path.isfile(path)` or `open(path)`?

Comment: I'm confused here... Those two functions do completely different things ... Are you asking about whether you should check if the file is there before you open it vs just trying to open it and catching exceptions if it fails?

Comment: performance is not an issue here, use `open(path)` and check for exceptions, avoiding potential race conditions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Testing helps. `os.path.isfile` is quite a bit faster than `open`:

```
In [475]: %timeit open('test_test.txt')
10000 loops, best of 3: 47.9 us per loop

In [476]: %timeit os.path.isfile('test_test.txt')
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.21 us per loop
```

But look at the run times. You need to open or check for **a lot** of files to have any practical impact on total run time for most applications.

Answer (score 3):

Mike has shown that `isfile()` is faster, but there are two more things to consider:

1. `isfile()` only tests if a file exists -- it doesn't tell you anything about read or write permissions! It is very rare to *just* want to know whether or not a file exists, you often want to test if you can do something with it. `open()` will tell you this.
2. Pythonic code generally prefers an EAFP ([Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092992/why-is-it-easier-to-ask-forgiveness-than-permission-in-python-but-not-in-java)) style, where you try to do things and catch exceptions if you can't. (The opposite is LBYL -- Look Before You Leap, which is common in Java and C, among other languages.)

Both these two points suggest you might be better off using `open()` unless you are *really* really pressed for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik `isfile()` will be faster while `open(path)` is more secure, in the sence that if `open()` is able to actually open the file, you can be sure it's there.

Comment: So, you're saying that you _can't_ be sure the file is there if you use `isfile()`? Can you give an example of a situation where `isfile` would give the wrong answer?

Comment: @Kevin -- All you know is that the file existed at the time `isfile` was run ... You don't know that the file still exists when you try to execute the next line of code (potential race condition)